# How to separate strings in a list in python?

Tags: python, string, list

Ok i have this `['state1', ',', 'state2,st6']` and I want it to be like this

```
[['state1'], ['state2'], ['st6']] or ['state1', 'state2', 'st6']
```

I dont understand lists that great and i tried myself and always the same, list has no attribute split, lstrip etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Why the nested lists at all? Why not `['state1', 'state2', 'st6']` for example?

Comment: Have you tried solving this problem yourself? If so, plese provide some relevant code

Comment: @martijnpieters ok or that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do, these are called [list comprehensions](http://carlgroner.me/Python/2011/11/09/An-Introduction-to-List-Comprehensions-in-Python.html):

```
>>> original = ['state1', ',', 'state2,st6']
>>> [[item] for string in original for item in string.split(',') if item]
[['state1'], ['state2'], ['st6']]
```

or if you don't want nested lists:

```
>>> [item for string in original for item in string.split(',') if item]
['state1', 'state2', 'st6']
```

Comment: thx man, so much trouble with lists, I will learn know :)

Comment: @CrveniZg good, glad I could help. If my answer was helpful to you, would you mind accepting it by clicking on the tick so it turns green? (after the grace period has passed, of course). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen ur previous version of same question ..i think above answers can only split if there is comma only . if u want to remove any symbol .. u can use this and different implementaion to learn

> `import re`
>
> `data=['state1', ',', 'state2','|','st6']`
>
> `p = r"^[\w'-]+$"`

```
 > def f(x):    
    >     if re.search(p, x):
    >         return True
    > 
    > print filter(f,data)
```

output :

```
> ['state1', 'state2', 'st6']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would join the list to string then split:

```
>>> a = ['state1', ',', 'state2,st6']
>>> [[i] for i in ''.join(a).split(',')]
[['state1'], ['state2'], ['st6']]
```